# Post Image from URL to Facebook PHP SDK using file_get_contents gets "(#324) Requires upload file"

Tags: php, facebook, file-get-contents

I'm trying to post a picture to Facebook from a URL but I keep getting an error:

> Exception occured, code: 324 with message: (#324) Requires upload file

I did upgrade to PHP 5.5 on my server. And I've tried to do it two ways, one with just `'source' => $img1,` where $img1 = 'http://domain./net/path/to/file.jpg' and I tried to read the file into a variable, but I'm probably not using the `file_get_contents`function right. I can't put the images in the same place as the PHP file because the pictures are being loaded from a different login than the page admin. Anyway here are the two ways I tried. I also tried to get the `"data:image/jpeg;base64,".`before the `file_get_contents`

I decided to try to use the `file_get_contents`function because in another stack overflow post the guy appeared to have luck [uploading the image as a string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256877/photo-upload-with-facebook-node-sdk-module-324-requires-upload-file)

```
<?
if($session) {

  try {
    $imagetopost = "data:image/jpeg;base64,".file_get_contents($img1, false, $context);
    // Upload to a user's profile. The photo will be in the
    // first album in the profile. You can also upload to
    // a specific album by using /ALBUM_ID as the path     
    $response = (new FacebookRequest(
      $session, 'POST', '/me/photos', array(
        'source' => $img1,
        //'message' => 'User provided message',
        //'place' => $business_place_id
      )
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject();

    // If you're not using PHP 5.5 or later, change the file reference to:
    // 'source' => '@/path/to/file.name'

    echo "Posted with id: " . $response->getProperty('id');

  } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

  }   

}
```

and:

```
<?
if($session) {

  try {
    $imagetopost = "data:image/jpeg;base64,".file_get_contents($img1, false, $context);
    // Upload to a user's profile. The photo will be in the
    // first album in the profile. You can also upload to
    // a specific album by using /ALBUM_ID as the path     
    $response = (new FacebookRequest(
      $session, 'POST', '/me/photos', array(
        'source' => $imagetopost,
        //'message' => 'User provided message',
        //'place' => $business_place_id
      )
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject();

    // If you're not using PHP 5.5 or later, change the file reference to:
    // 'source' => '@/path/to/file.name'

    echo "Posted with id: " . $response->getProperty('id');

  } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

  }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to init facebook client with additional parameter `fileUpload = true`

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I didn't need to use `file_get_contents`. I could just change `'source'` to `'url'` and then I could use the url to the image I wanted to use. From Facebook photos#publish page: [2: Use a photo that is already on the internet by publishing using the url parameter:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/photos#publish)